# Rails4 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Rails4 application running in production, and my visitors run occasionally into ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error, which I cant reproduce. I get 2-4 daily notifications from various forms, with no clear logic behind. The report I receive shows that authenticity_token submitted by the form is different from one kept in session. How is it possible? I managed to run into the problem myself few times, however it's impossible to reproduce, all of sudden authenticity_token for the form is different from the one stored in session and InvalidAuthenticityToken arises.
Any ideas where to start looking?

Example:

```
 Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : https://domain/signin
  * HTTP Method: POST
  * IP address : 113.96.xx.xx
  * Parameters : {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MOh9JDE1AZ0CbIw/M33vfhjRShwzI6oqMhi8lk+n7OE=", "email"=>"xxxx@xxx", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Sign In", "controller"=>"clients", "action"=>"signin", "locale"=>"en"}

-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

  * session id: [FILTERED]
  * data: {"_csrf_token"=>"QazCSVGeZlxEh83XTM+f5PkC/zopwCF96yV4duRats0="}
```

Update: Wanted to add that I'm serving the pages via two load balanced AWS EC2 instances, and store sessions in Redis ElastiCache instance

Comment: maybe your forms missing a hidden input field called `authenticate_token`, please show your view code for more info.

Comment: Are there redirects involved maybe? I had this problem earlier this week. I ended up calling the redirect later in my action.

Comment: if the field was missing I would get the error 100% of the time. It happens maybe in 0.1% form submissions. And no redirect here also. It seems like a cache for me, but why is it happening only sometimes.

Comment: Are you caching your forms?

Comment: no, thats was the first thing to check

Comment: You can't cache the entire form. If you want to cache the form, you have to cache after the form_for tag because then it won't include the caching of the authorization token input box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question, in case someone runs into the same issue, it seems like removing csrf_meta_tag from the header fixed the problem for us. I dont know why. Could be that rails javascript responsible for setting the auth_token was interfering in some way with our javascript and caused the problem, but my gut feeling is that it had to so something with cache, either on server or client side. Anyway, after removing csrf_meta_tag it seems like we got rid of the problem. Just make sure you're using the form_tag for all your forms.

Comment: It might be a mix between js and cookies but my bet is on cookies!

Answer (score 16):

Any forms generated by Rails (i.e. with `form_for` and such, not with you putting `<form>` in the template) will have the anti-CSRF token added as a hidden field when it's necessary. If you wrote the form yourself and didn't include the CSRF hidden input, then Rails relies on the CSRF meta tag and JavaScript for things to work. So if you wrote your own form and you didn't include the hidden field and if the client's JavaScript doesn't work for whatever reason, you can get this error. Because the "client's JavaScript doesn't work for whatever reason" clause is a difficult one to detect and debug, I actually intentionally removed the CSRF meta tag on my site. That way if I forgot to include the hidden input, it'll break for everyone (fast fail), I'd find out about it immediately, and I could fix it. I would recommend you do this as well.

With that being said, I would recommend you look at the access log for these "visitors". Do you see anything odd?

- Do they access the page that has the form on it immediately before submitting it? If not, maybe they're bots or actual, real-deal CSRF attempts (that's what this is checking for, isn't it? :)).
- Did they load the form on one EC2 and end up submitting to another? If so, can you turn one EC2 off and see if the errors go away?
- Did they somehow lose their session? This could be your problem or theirs.

Comment: Well, if the token was simply missing, I guess I would get no "authenticity_token" at all in my params, and not the wrong one.

Comment: Despite of the fact that the issue it not solved yet, but as the bounty period is coming to an end, and since this answer is the most relevant to my question "Any ideas where to start looking?" I'm going to award bounty here.

Comment: Thanks. If you post the answers to the questions I gave you, I may be able to help further.

Comment: Would there be any risk to do this hidden field ?

Answer (score 4):

Since rails uses JavaScript to append the `authenticity_token` to rails forms, I would double-triple check that you don't have a runtime JS error based of of dynamic content that is causing this heisenbug. If a JS error we're to break the whole application.js file, your forms would be invalid. Is this possible?

Comment: Very good point, however I couldt find any js issue so far. Actually I even tried removing csrf_meta_tag from header, and it still works, and still arises the error randomly

Comment: Forms should **not** work if you remove the csrf meta tag. There must be something different from the code you are writing and the code you are deploying.

Comment: Forms work just fine without the csrf meta tag if you let Rails generate the form tag. See my answer.

Comment: Yep, I'm using form_tag everywhere and forms work just fine without csrf_meta_tag, this eliminates possible javascript issues, it has to do something with sessions I believe

Answer (score 1):

That it happens on sign in makes me suspect something may be wrong on your sign out, triggering the issue for users that sign out and immediately back in again.

Signing out usually destroys the current user session and replaces it with a new one, invalidating the CSRF tag. Usually this isn't an issue, since the user gets redirected to another page containing the new CSRF tag.

I can see this being an issue if

- logout leads to a page that might be cached, either in the browser or a proxy
- logout is done through AJAX, which in rare instances fails to do the right thing on success, failing to update the CSRF tag

Comment: Actually the error arises on different forms(and I have really many of them), not just sign in. I just happened to give example from sign in. Logout procedure is pretty common though, get request reulsting with  reset_session and redirect to root_path

Answer (score 1):

I had same trouble.
Server: nginx + passenger

**nginx.conf:**

```
http {
    ...
    expires    90d;
    ...
    server {
        server_name domain1.com
        ...
    }
    server {
        server_name domain2.com
        ...
    }
    server {
        server_name domain_3_with_rails.com
        ...
    }
}
```

Problems in instruction "expires 90d;"
Browser locally cached page with form and with authenticity_token.

**Solution:** add `"expires 0d;"` for rails domains:

**nginx.conf:**

```
http {
    ...
    expires    90d;
    ...
    server {
        server_name domain1.com
        ...
    }
    server {
        server_name domain2.com
        ...
    }
    server {
        server_name domain_3_with_rails.com
        expires 0d;
        ...
    }
}
```

After that, be sure to restart Nginx.

For those who have apache: apache it certainly has a similar statement "expires" for nginx

Comment: What does `expires` do? Are you making all cookies on that domain expire immediately?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue as of now. I have been poking around and I noticed that if I turn cookies off (block the domain to be able to use cookies) I will run into a ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken everytime I do a `POST`.

So the user has JS enabled but does not allow cookies.

AFAIK the anti-CSRF token in Rails is sent as a session cookie server side, and then fails since the cookie could not be set.

Comment: If you disable cookies  then it will fail with InvalidAuthenticityToken error because the token must be sent with the session cookie or retrieved from other session store (memcached, redis, database) using the session id stored in the cookie